# I want the last entries in my Microsoft SQL Server database but get duplication

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My problem is that I want to start a database query which should give me the last (maxDate) entry of every Serial number.

I am working with a Microsoft SQL Server database.

The first picture shows all entries in the database:

[image]

After I have run the following code I get this output:

```
string aQuery =  @" SELECT *
    FROM (
          SELECT SerialNumber, MAX(Date) as MaxDate
          FROM eBox_Deploy
          GROUP BY SerialNumber
    ) r
INNER JOIN eBox_Deploy t
ON t.SerialNumber = r.SerialNumber AND t.Date = r.MaxDate";

using (var db = new eBoxDataContext())
{
    list.AddRange(db.ExecuteQuery<eBox_Deploy>(bQuery)); 
}
```

After picture:

[image]

Now my problem is that I have duplicates because they already exists in the database. `Distinct` doesn't work well because these all have different Id´s.

How can I get them away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use windowed functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,
         rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [SerialNumber] ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
     FROM eBox_Deploy) AS sub
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If your `[Date]` is not unique within `SerialNumber` group use `RANK()` to get ties.